# How to reload UIViewController after changing UISegmentedControl

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a viewController with UISegmentedControl to switch between 2 contents (by department or by recipe). When I toggle the segmentedControl (which will execute the changeColor function), I want to change the content corresponding to which segment is selected. The contents in each segment are several UILabel then add them like view.addSubview(label). However, what my current code do is placing them overlap each other.

```
class GroceryViewController: UIViewController {

    var customSC = UISegmentedControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupSegmentedControl()
        contentByDepartment()
    }

    func setupSegmentedControl() {
        let items = ["BY DEPARTMENT", "BY RECIPE"]
        customSC = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
        customSC.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

        let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        customSC.frame = CGRect(x:frame.minX + 15, y:frame.minY + 100,
                                width:frame.width - 30, height:frame.height * 0.04)
        customSC.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        customSC.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F7F7F7")
        customSC.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(hexString: "#FC6A03")], for: UIControl.State.selected)
        customSC.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeColor), for: .valueChanged)
        view.addSubview(customSC)
    }

    @objc func changeColor(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                contentByDepartment() // contents are several UILabel adding to view as SubView
            case 1:
                contentByRecipe() // contents are several UILabel adding to view as SubView
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}
```

I have searched for the solution and mostly they are "reloadData() in UITableView", which I don't have one. So I have no idea how to reload this viewController without bothering UIView or UITableView.

The question is: Is it possible to reload the viewController alone from some function so that previous content will be clear out before displaying selected contents and how to do so ?

EDIT: code of contentByDepartment and contentByRecipe

```
func contentByDepartment() {
        let recipeHeader = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:50, y:180, width: 200, height: 20))
        recipeHeader.setActivityDescription(label: "Coffee and Tea")
        recipeHeader.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#FC6A03")
        recipeHeader.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)

        let ingredient1Name = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:70,y:210,width:200,height:20))
        ingredient1Name.setActivityDescription(label: "Green tea leaves")
        ingredient1Name.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

        let ingredient1Amount = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:72,y:230,width:200,height:20))
        ingredient1Amount.setActivityDescription(label: "1 tablespoons")
        ingredient1Amount.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

        let ingredient2Name = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:70,y:260,width:200,height:20))
        ingredient2Name.setActivityDescription(label: "Coffee powder")
        ingredient2Name.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

        let ingredient2Amount = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:72,y:280,width:200,height:20))
        ingredient2Amount.setActivityDescription(label: "3 tablespoons")
        ingredient2Amount.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

        view.addSubview(recipeHeader)
        view.addSubview(ingredient1Name)
        view.addSubview(ingredient1Amount)
        view.layer.addSublayer(drawLine(x1:70, y1:255, x2:350, y2:255, lineWidth:0.3))
        view.addSubview(ingredient2Name)
        view.addSubview(ingredient2Amount)
        view.layer.addSublayer(drawLine(x1:0, y1:310, x2:420, y2:310, lineWidth:0.5))
}

func contentByRecipe() {
        let recipeHeader = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:50, y:180, width: 200, height: 20))
        recipeHeader.setActivityDescription(label: "Cha-yen")
        recipeHeader.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#FC6A03")
        recipeHeader.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)

        let ingredient1Name = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:70,y:210,width:200,height:20))
        ingredient1Name.setActivityDescription(label: "Vanilla extract")
        ingredient1Name.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

        let ingredient1Amount = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:72,y:230,width:200,height:20))
        ingredient1Amount.setActivityDescription(label: "1 tablespoons")
        ingredient1Amount.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

        let ingredient2Name = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:70,y:260,width:200,height:20))
        ingredient2Name.setActivityDescription(label: "Sugar")
        ingredient2Name.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

        let ingredient2Amount = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:72,y:280,width:200,height:20))
        ingredient2Amount.setActivityDescription(label: "3 tablespoons")
        ingredient2Amount.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

        view.addSubview(recipeHeader)
        view.addSubview(ingredient1Name)
        view.addSubview(ingredient1Amount)
        view.layer.addSublayer(drawLine(x1:70, y1:255, x2:350, y2:255, lineWidth:0.3))
        view.addSubview(ingredient2Name)
        view.addSubview(ingredient2Amount)
        view.layer.addSublayer(drawLine(x1:0, y1:310, x2:420, y2:310, lineWidth:0.5))
}
```

Comment: Your current code seems to do what you want... What does your current code do?

Comment: It did change the contents but they will overlapped each other. What I hope to do is reload it so that previous one will be cleared out first, then display the selected contents

Comment: Then _clear out the previous one first_. You have to do this yourself. No one's gonna do it for you... You can use loop through the `subviews` of the superview of the views you want to remove, and call `removeFromSuperView`. Alternatively, add the department and recipe content views as subviews of different views. This way you can just show/hide the corresponding superviews when the segmented control changes.

Comment: If you show `contentByDepartment` and `contentByRecipe`, I can probably post an answer.

Comment: I have edited the post to show those 2 functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn to group related views together. Right now, you are adding all your views as subviews of `view`. This is very unorganised, and has led you to your current situation - not being able to show/hide certain views efficiently.

One way to organise your views is to add your "by department" views into a big `UIView`, and all the "by recipe" views into another big `UIView`.

```
var byDepartmentContainerView: UIView!
func setUpContentByDepartment() {
    let recipeHeader = UILabel(frame: ...)
    recipeHeader.setActivityDescription(label: "Coffee and Tea")
    recipeHeader.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#FC6A03")
    recipeHeader.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)

    let ingredient1Name = UILabel(frame: ...)
    ingredient1Name.setActivityDescription(label: "Green tea leaves")
    ingredient1Name.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

    let ingredient1Amount = UILabel(frame: ...)
    ingredient1Amount.setActivityDescription(label: "1 tablespoons")
    ingredient1Amount.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

    let ingredient2Name = UILabel(frame: ...)
    ingredient2Name.setActivityDescription(label: "Coffee powder")
    ingredient2Name.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

    let ingredient2Amount = UILabel(frame: ...)
    ingredient2Amount.setActivityDescription(label: "3 tablespoons")
    ingredient2Amount.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

    byDepartmentContainerView = UIView(frame: ...)

    byDepartmentContainerView.addSubview(recipeHeader)
    byDepartmentContainerView.addSubview(ingredient1Name)
    byDepartmentContainerView.addSubview(ingredient1Amount)
    byDepartmentContainerView.addSubview(ingredient2Name)
    byDepartmentContainerView.addSubview(ingredient2Amount)
}

var byRecipeContainerView: UIView!
func setUpContentByRecipe() {
    let recipeHeader = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:50, y:180, width: 200, height: 20))
    recipeHeader.setActivityDescription(label: "Cha-yen")
    recipeHeader.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#FC6A03")
    recipeHeader.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)

    let ingredient1Name = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:70,y:210,width:200,height:20))
    ingredient1Name.setActivityDescription(label: "Vanilla extract")
    ingredient1Name.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

    let ingredient1Amount = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:72,y:230,width:200,height:20))
    ingredient1Amount.setActivityDescription(label: "1 tablespoons")
    ingredient1Amount.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

    let ingredient2Name = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:70,y:260,width:200,height:20))
    ingredient2Name.setActivityDescription(label: "Sugar")
    ingredient2Name.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

    let ingredient2Amount = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:72,y:280,width:200,height:20))
    ingredient2Amount.setActivityDescription(label: "3 tablespoons")
    ingredient2Amount.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

    byRecipeContainerView = UIView(frame: ...)
    byRecipeContainerView.addSubview(recipeHeader)
    byRecipeContainerView.addSubview(ingredient1Name)
    byRecipeContainerView.addSubview(ingredient1Amount)
    byRecipeContainerView.addSubview(ingredient2Name)
    byRecipeContainerView.addSubview(ingredient2Amount)
}
```

Note that I've omitted the frames of the views. Please give the container views a frame large enough to contain all its subviews, and adjust the subview's frames so that they are *relative to the container view's coordinate system*.

Also, you seem to be drawing the same lines in both methods, so it can be done once and never again.

```
func drawLines() {
    view.layer.addSublayer(drawLine(x1:0, y1:310, x2:420, y2:310, lineWidth:0.5))
    view.layer.addSublayer(drawLine(x1:70, y1:255, x2:350, y2:255, lineWidth:0.3))
}
```

In `viewDidLoad`, you can call all three methods:

```
setUpContentByDepartment()
setUpContentByRecipe()
drawLines()
view.addSubview(byDepartmentContainerView)
view.addSubview(byRecipeContainerView)
byRecipeContainerView.isHidden = true
```

Now you can just do something like:

```
switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        byRecipeContainerView.isHidden = true
        byDepartmentContainerView.isHidden = false
    case 1:
        byRecipeContainerView.isHidden = false
        byDepartmentContainerView.isHidden = true
    default:
        break
}
```

---

P.S. hardcoding view's frames is a very bad idea. It's not localisable, not adaptable to different devices, among other things. Please learn about [Autolayout Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much.  Your solution is very clear and organised. I have learned a lot from this and I will try to learn more about what you suggest.